# reverse function for a char* throwing segmentation fault

Tags: c++, string, segmentation-fault

I have the following simple function:

```
void reverse(char* str) {
    if (str == NULL)
        return;
    char* end = str;
    while(*end != NULL) {
        end++;
    }
    end--;  
    while(str < end){
        char temp = *str;
        *str++ = *end;
        *end-- = temp;
    }   
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char* second = "SOMETHING\0";
    cout << "Before Reverse String: " << second << '\n';
    reverse(second);
    cout << "Reverse String: " << second << '\n';
}
```

Simple, right? however I'm getting a Segmentation Fault in lines

```
*str++ = *end 
*end-- = temp
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: You are modifying a string literal which is undefined behavior.

Comment: see [Reverse a char array](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/14951/)

Comment: This is not valid C++11, since you cannot have a non-const `char *` to a string literal, and you should get a warning about it regardless. Please either listen to the warnings, or turn them on and then do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are modifying a string literal:

```
char* second = "SOMETHING\0";
```

which is undefined behavior, one solution would be to assign the literal to char array:

```
char second[] = "SOMETHING";
```

Also,string literals will be NULL terminated, so not need to add the `\0`. You should also modify your while loop to compare with `\0` instead of `NULL`. Although, it should work since they both will evaluate to `0` since `*end` is a `char` it reads better to use `\0`:

```
while(*end != '\0')
```

Comment: As far as I know, `NULL` must evaluate to 0, and `'\0'` must have the value 0. It's definitely a lot clearer than `NULL`, though.

Comment: @chris Both `g++` and `clang++` warn something akin to `comparison between NULL and non-pointer ('char' and NULL)` and although it should work fine I think using `\0` reads better. Amended to be more specific.

Comment: There's that, too. Warnings are never nice to have around when they're this easy to get rid of.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
char* second = "SOMETHING\0";
```

To

```
char second[] = "SOMETHING";
```

Note: string literals are not modifiable, and you don't have to explicitly add `\0` in a string literal.

```
while(*end != NULL) {
```

should be

```
while(*end != '\0') {
```

`NULL` is used for null pointer only.